# how many partitions and equivalence relations of A = {a,b,c} exists for example or A {a,b,c,d,e}?

Tags: equivalence-relations, set-partition

I have these two questions. Is there a formel or anything like that to find how many partitions and equivalence relations there is for A? I know the answer but i don´t know how to calculate it by my self. 
I would appreciate if anyone could explain how it works.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have [this recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions)

To prove it, for a set of $n+1$ elements, single out one element $a$. Then there are $\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose $n-k$ other elements among the other $n$ elements to be in the class of $a$, when that class ought to have $n-k$ elements. For each of those there are $B_k$ ways to partition the remaining $k$ elements. Summing for all the cases for the size $n-k=0,1,...,n$ of the class of $a$, you get the value of $B_{n+1}$.